# How to pass value as array by input field

Tags: php, jquery, html

If a user selects a checkbox, related value is stored in a hidden input field by jQuery and passes to the PHP page after form submit. If the user selects multiple checkboxes, concerned values are added as array into the hidden input field. But after submitting the form I am finding the array of input field is not an array and I am unable to fetch the array from the input field.

HTML of the page:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="selected" id="selected" value="" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" class="check_list" value="'.$row['id'].'" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" class="check_list" value="'.$row['id'].'" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" class="check_list" value="'.$row['id'].'" />
```

jQuery code for adding an ID while any checkbox is selected:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var ids = [];
    $(".check_list").change(function(){  //  <-----correct here
      code = $(this).val();
      ids.push(code);
      $("#selected").val(ids);
      });
    });
```

form processing by PHP

```
 foreach($_POST['selected'] as $key=>$value){
     foreach($value as $keygen){
      echo $keygen.'<br />';
     }
    }
```

But I can't get the selected checkbox value by above. If I change processing part of PHP like the below and if a user selects all three checkboxes then:

```
   echo $_POST['selected'];
```

is showing as `23,56,57`. (I suppose these are the values of the selected checkboxes.)

How can I implement the above things in such way so that I can pass the selected values as an array of the input field and can fetch them accordingly. I want something like this:

```
 $_POST['selected'] = array(23,56,57)
```

so that I can get particular array element like this:

```
 $_POST['selected'][1] = 56;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$myArray=explode(",",$_POST['selected']);
$myArray[1] = 56;
```

or

```
foreach(explode(",",$_POST['selected']) as $key=>$value){
  foreach($value as $keygen){
    echo $keygen.'<br />';
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to explode for some coding purpose. I have to use foreach loop directly.

Comment: can you use this syntax? explode(",",$_POST['selected'])[1]

Comment: Nope, I have to use foreach loop directly

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the array in hidden field, set comma separated string in the hidden field and the split the value on server side and stored that into the array to have access.

#### HTML

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="one"/>
 <input type="checkbox" value="two"/>
 <input type="checkbox" value="three"/>
 <input type="hidden" id="data"/>    
 <button>Submit</button>
```

#### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = "";
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr("checked") === "checked") {
                data = data + $(this).val() + ",";
            }
        });
        data = data.substring(0, data.lastIndexOf(","));
        //setting the comma separated string into the hidden element
        $("#data").val(data);
        data = "";

    });

});
```

Comment: The code I mentioned actually sending the value as comma separated string because when I am echoing the $_POST['selected'], I am finding the selected values as comma separated values. If your intension is to send value as comma separated then my code is the simpler and shorter than you.